# How do I hold ephemeral data in a function class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, queue, message-queue

I need to make a messaging queue. I receive a message, run transformations on it and send it to an output queue.

```
import queue
import json
import re

Class example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outputZero  = queue.Queue()
        self.outputOne   = queue.Queue()

   def transform(self, msg):
        messageDict = json.loads(msg)
        keys = [i for i in messageDict.keys()]

        for i in keys:             
            # reverse strings that include "bonkers
            if re.search("bonkers", str(messageDict[i])):
                messageDict[i] = messageDict[i][::-1]

        return messageDict

    def dispatch(self, msg):
        if "_special" in keys:
            self.outputZero.put(messageDict)
        elif "hash" in keys:
            self.outputOne.put(messageDict)

    def enqueue(self, msg):
       #transform the message
       cleanmsg = self.transform(msg)
       #dispatch the message
       self.dispatch(cleanmsg)
```

The problem is that I need to deal with sequences. I need to be able to handle messages that include two parts, a `_sequence` that is an id for the sequence and a `_part` that is the message number in the sequence, starting with zero.

I need to use the first message in a sequence to determine the queue for all the rest and then send them, in the right order, to whatever queue is determined based on the first message.

This is an example of a few messages.

```
input00 = '{"thefield": "themessage", "_privatefield" : "content", "_sequence" : "aeiou", "_part":"3"}' 
input01 = '{"thefield": "onemore", "_privatefield" : "content", "_sequence" : "aeiou", "_part":"1"}'
input02 = '{"thefield": "yetanother", "_privatefield" : "content", "_sequence" : "aeiou", "_part":"2"}' 
input03 = '{"thefield": "lastone", "_privatefield" : "content", "_sequence" : "aeiou", "_part":"0"}'
```

My solution is to store a dictionary that has each sequence id and whether part 0 has been included and the current dictionary that is 'up next'. Something like this.

```
sequenceDict[input["_sequence"]]["_part"] = input00
```

Then, I can include an if statement that trigger when the 0th `_part` is included for a sequence and another that send offs each series of parts in the right order.

Sorry this has been long. My question is, how can I store such a dictionary in my class `example` without it being ephemeral and just disappearing when a new command gets run?

Comment: Is the answer *not* “assign to an attribute on `self`”?